# Angular mocking Observable does not update component template in Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I try to mock a value of an observable in a service that gets injected to the component, but the changes are not reflected to the components template.

I create the instance of the service as follows:

```
let component: AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let dataService = jasmine.createSpyObj<DataService>('DataService', ['fetchData']);

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: DataService, useValue: dataService }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

And then I want to use and mock the service in a test as follows:

```
it('should fetch and display data', () => {
  const testData = ['Test Item 1', 'Test Item 2'];
  dataService.fetchData.and.returnValue(of(testData));

  // Calls fetchData on service
  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const element = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  // Works
  expect(component.data).toHaveSize(2);
  // Does not work, content is empty
  expect(element.querySelector('p').textContent).toContain('Test Item 1, Test Item 2');
});
```

I also tried it with fakeAsync and tick but that has not worked either. What do I have to do so that the changes are reflected to the template and I can mock the service with the data that is needed for the test? A stud is no option because I need to mock different scenarios like throwing errors and invalid data. I also can't mock the service in the beforeAll method because in some cases I want to test what the component looks like before data fetching.

Edit added component:
Edit2 added template:
The components code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p>{{ data.join(', ') }}</p>`,,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'UpdateTest';
  data: string[] = [];

  constructor(private store: Store, private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.fetchData().pipe(
      tap((response) => this.data = response)
    ).subscribe();
  }
}

// Html Template Code
<p>{{ data.join(', ') }}</p>
```

Comment: When does `fetchData` gets called? if you want to check the template, you need to call detect change after calling `fetchData` method.

Comment: @rsangin Oh I simplified the code to much for the question, it is called in ngOnInit and I called component.ngOnInit() in the test and then triggered changeDetection

Comment: Can you show your component code as well? Are you running `OnPush` change detection in the component?

Comment: @AliF50 Added the components code